# How to update rally defect using web service v2.0

Tags: java, web-services, rally

I have ObjectID of defect.
Defect should be updated using only web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a security token using this endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize
```

The result includes the token, "fbaa0c04-2616-....
{"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "SecurityToken": "fbaa0c04-2616-...."}}

Post using 'create' endpoint with the security token appended in the end. In this example 123456789 is the OID of the defect where Description field is being updated

URL:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/123456789?key=fbaa0c04-...

Request Body:

{ 
"Defect":{ 
"Description":"some description" 
} 
}

Here is another example of a Request Body (payload) where two fields are updated, one of which is the Owner, which is a reference to a User object. Reference fields must use ObjectID:

{"Defect":{
"State":"Open",
"Owner":"/user/987654321"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the [Rally Rest Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava) helpful.

The following example shows a full CRUD lifecycle:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blob/master/src/main/resources/examples/com/rallydev/rest/CrudExample.java